# How i can clear the WebView's content with javaFX by clicking on a button?

Tags: web, view, javafx

I want to know how to clear the webview's content just by clicking on a button with javaFX? So how I can do that? For example: WebView1 contains google web page while clicking on a button should this page clear

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can clear the web view by loading some empty content:

```
webView.getEngine().loadContent("");
```

Complete example:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebBrowser extends Application {

    private TextField textField ;
    private WebView webView ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        webView = new WebView();
        textField = new TextField("https://www.google.com");
        textField.setOnAction(e -> load());
        load();

        Button clearButton = new Button("Clear");
        clearButton.setOnAction(e -> webView.getEngine().loadContent(""));
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(webView, new HBox(10, textField, clearButton), null, null, null);

        textField.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private void load() {
        String url = makeUrl(textField.getText()) ;
        webView.getEngine().load(url);
        textField.setText(url);
    }


    private String makeUrl(String text) {
        if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+:.+", text)) {
            return text ;
        } else return "http://"+text ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```